# Remove pricing fields from gravity form

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am using gravity from product addon. When sending mails, Woo-commerce embeds Gform data in the product and send to customer and admin. I want to send that email to moderator too but don't want to show him prices and discounts. for that I am using WP advance notification,  which contains an email template.I am able to remove TOTAL price field from that but unable to remove total price from gravity form data. it is showing price of product along with product name. for e.g

```
Selected City: XXX
Selected Product : Packets ($10.00)
Quantity : 1
Tax : 5% = $0.05
Total : $9.95
Mode of Payment: Credit Card
```

all of that data is coming from array "gravity_form_history". I hid price manually by overwriting array indices. but,
My supervisor wants me to give a general solution. If he adds more products with gforms, then he only has to enter fields names somewhere, to hide/remove prices/values of that field only, not labels). He don't want to play with code.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution If someone need it.

I used woocommerce's "$item_meta" array tp capture gform data.

```
foreach ($item_meta->meta as $arraydata => $arrayvalue)
                {

                    if (    $arraydata == "_qty" ||
                            $arraydata  == "_tax_class" ||
                            $arraydata  == "_product_id" ||
                            $arraydata  == "_gravity_forms_history" ||
                    // all values above are general and will be there in default customer email.
                    // below arraydata is from gravity form
                            $arraydata  == "Total" ||
                            $arraydata  == "Delivery charges")
                    {}
                else
                    {
                        $string = preg_replace("/\d+\.\d+/", "", $arrayvalue[0]); 
                        $string = str_replace('($)', '', $string);
                        // printing Filds : Value
                         echo $arraydata.": ".$string."<br>";
                    }

                }
```

This will return Fields from gform with values with them except those who are mentioned in if condition. preg_replace is used to remove product prices, discount prices and percents, taxes if applicable from values. for e.g it will change

```
Selected Product : Headphones ($25.45), Mouse ($15.00), Keyboard(with backlight) ($45.00)
Total Price : $85.45
Payment Gateway: Credit Card
```

to

```
Selected Product : Headphones , Mouse , Keyboard(with backlight)
Payment Gateway: Credit Card
```

The file in which all this happens will send an email to a specific email address via Wordpress Advance Notification plugin.